# Why Java allocates just 36 Gb of memory of 110 Gb of k8s pod

Tags: kubernetes, jvm, heap-memory

I have container with ~112 GB memory in Kubernetes.
Single java application (Spring Boot) is deployed in it. Print args shows this

```
...Application - -server -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -Xms110g -Xmx110g
```

Output from JVM shows than only 36GB heap available for process.

```
private static final long GIGABYTE = 1024L * 1024L * 1024L;

public static float bytesToGigabytes(long bytes) {
    return Math.floorDiv(bytes / GIGABYTE, 3);
}

public void getMemUsed() {
    // Get the Java runtime
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    // Run the garbage collector
    runtime.gc();
    // Calculate the used memory
    long memory = runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory();
    log.info("RAM Used %.3fGb of %.3fGb (max %.3fGb)".formatted(
            bytesToGigabytes(memory), bytesToGigabytes(runtime.totalMemory()), bytesToGigabytes(runtime.maxMemory())));

}
```

prints

```
RAM Used 0.000Gb of 36.000Gb
...
RAM Used 29.000Gb of 36.000Gb
```

While tools like "heap" and "jps" shows another picture

```
    free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          125Gi       102Gi        15Gi       118Mi       8.3Gi        22Gi
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

[top shell command output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzxKM.jpg)

PS: when the memory grows above 33-35 GB, pod restarts

May be related to this
[Linux: Cannot allocate more than 32 GB/64 GB of memory in a single process due to virtual memory limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30173133/linux-cannot-allocate-more-than-32-gb-64-gb-of-memory-in-a-single-process-due-t)

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Just add this JVM params

```
-XX:+UseContainerSupport -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=100
```

and also change the memory calc function to

```
log.info("RAM used {} of {} (max {})", FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize(memory),
            FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize(runtime.totalMemory()),
            FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize(runtime.maxMemory()));
```